# Replace/strip empty lines using gsub

Tags: ruby, replace, gsub

I have an HTML page:

```
    <strong>

    Product Name:




</strong>
```

I want to strip its empty lines (`^\n` or `^$`). Expected HTML is:

```
    <strong>
    Product Name:
</strong>
```

Here is my syntax:

```
r.gsub!(/^\\n/, '')
```

It doesn't seem to work. I tried many combinations and I can't get it to do anything. `puts r.class => string` and `r` always have spaces in them. I'm actually trying a larger set of reductions:

```
r.gsub!(/\\n\s+?/, '').gsub!(/\\t\s+?/, '').gsub!(/^\\n/, '')
```

Comment: Can you give a short example of input and the expected output? I believe, by default, Ruby will only look at the first line of a string, you may need to include the `m` option in your regex.

Comment: @JustinWood  '                          <strong>

                              Product Name:




                          </strong>' If I can get this in here.  Just a lot of blank space on blank lines.  BTW Justin Wood of Adium fame?  Cheers

Comment: You want to convert two successive newlines to one: `str.gsub(/\n\n/,"\n")`.  Be sure to double-quote the replacement newline character.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Hi there.  This whole HTML page has variable amounts of several empty lines.  So just choosing 2 won't work here.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that you are escaping backslashes when you shouldn't be.  E.g.  `/\\n/` will match the string `\n`, not a newline character.  `/\n/` will match a newline character.  Same goes for `\t`.

If you want to play around with Ruby regular expressions, I recommend checking out [Rubular](http://rubular.com).

Also, be careful with `gsub!`, especially chaining them like that. `gsub!` returns `nil` if nothing is replaced and you will get an undefined method for nil error on subsequent calls.  You're much better off with

```
r = r.gsub(...).gsub(...) ...
```

Comment: Hi there.  Been doing this for years.  I just don't know if there's a problem with gsub!  This is what I have now:   r = r.gsub(/\t\s+?/, '')
 r = r.gsub(/^\n/, '') and the second one doesn't take out blank lines with zero spaces.

Comment: The problem is that it works fine in BBEdit.  I can't get Ruby to get this done.  Hence the confusion.  This is remedial but it isn't responding.

Comment: The problem with `gsub!` is that it returns `nil` if nothing is replaced.  So if you have `string = 'abc'` and you call `string.gsub!(/d/).gsub!(/a/)`, `string.gsub!(/d/)` returns nil and then `gsub!(/a/)` is called on `nil`, which is an exception.  If they were called without the bangs then it would be fine.  I have been bitten by it and seen others bitten by it so I tend to avoid it.

Comment: Ya I replaced that.  There wasn't a problem with any of that before.  It was returning the same as it went in.  I should have broken it up then built the compound statement after.  I see how a first problem can mask further attempts.  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work.

```
r = r.gsub(/\t\s+?/, "")
r = r.gsub(/^\s*$/, "")
```

The `"\n"` can be encapsulated by `\s*`.  `$` does not mean `\n`.

Comment: `\t\s` is not necessary. `\s` already includes `\t`. Check out the definition of `\s` in [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes).

Comment: Ya I knew that.  I'm tired.  Been a long day.  Thanks.